# local host can not display output map create in javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, openlayers, npm-install, openlayers-3

This workshop document from openlayers

```
https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/basics/
```

contains an example. i am trying to get it running but despite both of

```
npm start
npm run build
```

run successfully, however when i access the localhost"please see the attached image"

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

OR

```
http://localhost:1234/
```

nothing is to be displayed.
please let me know how to solve this issue

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "app6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5"
```

}
}

**image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't stop the process.

```
npm start
```

Then let the server running (nicht abbrechen) and go to:

```
http://localhost:1234/
```

If you run:

```
npm run build
```

you have to copy the build folder to a server to have it run.